# how to upload multiple images in to a server?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I tried to upload the image in to the server using Flex.The coding is compiled and run sucessfully but the images are upload at a time. i want to upload images seperately and also put progres bar to upload each image uploaded. can any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achive this with the FileReferenceList, you can find all the info and example code here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReferenceList.html